# Getting warning Trying to send command for object without authority

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity multiplayer so just learning it's concepts. I have this script on my player

```
private void Start()
{
    if (isServer)
    {
        //run when if it's server
    } else
    {
        //run if its client
        this.InstantiateBullet();
    }

}

[Command]
void InstantiateBullet()
{
    Debug.Log("Test Command");
}
```

I'm getting a warning "Trying to send command for object without authority. ShootHooks.InstantiateBullet" My question is do I have to assign my host player prefab to client an authority so it can call InstantiateBullet() without getting warning? Or can I just ignore the warning

Answer (score 1):

As the error/warning tells you you may only call commands from an object you have the authority over.

Currently it is running on all instances of your player prefab, also the ones that belong to the other connected players and you don't have the authority over those but they do!

So simply make an additional check

```
private void Start()
{
    if(hasAuthority)
    {
        if(isServer)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            InstantiateBullet();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to add my server player prefab authority to the client but it's not working

[Command(ignoreAuthority = true)]
void ServerPlayertoClientAuth()
{
    this.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().AssignClientAuthority(connectionToClient);
}

Comment: @Newboy11 your local player object **always** already has the authority by default .. you don't have to do anything at all